# onRecieve show a single ripple effect on imageView

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to be able to show to my users whenever they recieve a new location update in my app.

So, whenever `onRecieve()` is called in my activity I want a `imageView` to animate a *single* ripple effect.

Ive tried to find a appropriate librabry that can do this easily but with no success.

Given my requirements can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest a good way to accomplish this?

Using this library https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background i couldnt make a single ripple effect.. it never stops until i call stopRippleAnimation();

**Edit:** Using a valueanimator was a perfect solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call stopRippleAnimation after the ripple animation duration.

Also you can easily perform this animation using valueAnimator, Fadeout and scale using the values between 0 and 1.